# Removing all elements containing (",") from a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

```
muutujad = list(input("Muutujad (sisesta formaadis A,B,C,...): "))
while "," in muutujad == True:
    muutujad.remove(",")
print (muutujad)
```

My brain says that this code should remove all the commas from the list and in the end
the list should contain only ["A","B","C" ....] but it still contains all the elements. When i tried to visualize the code online, it said like [ "," in muutujad ] is always False but when i check the same command from the console it says it is True. I know it is a simple question but i would like to understand the basics.

Comment: In python a string is immutable. You must reassign value "muutujad = muutujad.remove(",")" for save changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension instead of a while loop:

```
muutujad = [elem for elem in muutujad if elem != ',']
```

Your `if` test itself is also wrong. You *never* need to test for `== True` for `if` in any case, that's what `if` *does*. But in your case you test the following:

```
("," in muutujad) and (muutujad == True)
```

which is *always* going to be False. In python, comparison operators like `in` and `==` are [chained](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/expressions.html#not-in). Leaving off the `== True` would make your `while` loop work much better.

I'm not sure you understand what happens when you call `list()` on a string though; it'll split it into individual characters:

```
>>> list('Some,string')
['S', 'o', 'm', 'e', ',', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```

If you wanted to split the input into elements separated by a comma, use the `.split()` method instead, and you won't have to remove the commas at all:

```
>>> 'Some,string'.split(',')
['Some', 'string']
```

Comment: Thanks! But read the last comment, I would like to know, what is the problem in my code.

Comment: So you first convert a string to a list, then you make a new list to eliminate the commas?

Comment: Exactly, im using the while command to remove all the commas one by one until "," in muutujad == False

Comment: @Faz3r: added an explanation.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand it now.

Comment: I didn't downvote you but I think someone was unhappy because you said "calling list() on a string, *splits* it into individual characters" which is technically not correct. There is no splitting going on. Calling `list` is just walking through the iterable and adding individual elements to the list which in this case turn out to be "one char strings". Also, your analysis of the users' test condition seems off. His test condition is not equivalent to `("," in muutujad) and (muutujad == True)` as your second code snippet says. It's equivalent to `"," in muutujad`. That's what I think. :)

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma read the 'chaining' link in Martijn's post - he is, in fact, exactly right that `"," in muutujad == True` is equivalent to `("," in muutujad) and (muutujad == True)`. It is expanded using the same rules that give `4 < 5 < 6` as `True` instead of `SyntaxError`. It certainly isn't the same as `"," in muutujad` - eg, `"," in "hello, world" == True` gives `False`.

Comment: @lvc: My bad; for some reason my eyes automatically added braces to OP's code snippet so I thought Martijn was rightly commenting on his explicit use of `True` and wrongly commenting about the execution order.

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma: The *effect* is the same; you end up with a list with individual characters. I try to scale the explanations to the level of the question asker, and diving into sequences and iterables and such is sometimes a level too far.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Well, dropping the use of the word "split" and saying something like "list called on a string creates a new list containing all the characters of the string" would have been clearer IMHO. But then again, I'm just guessing the reason why someone might have downvoted your post. I personally have no qualms with the content as it stands.

Answer (score 1):

The best option here is to simply parse the string in a better way:

```
>>> muutujad = input("Muutujad (sisesta formaadis A,B,C,...): ").split(",")
Muutujad (sisesta formaadis A,B,C,...): A, B, C
>>> muutujad
['A', ' B', ' C']
```

[`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) is a much better option for what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Yeah, the split command seems to work best in my code :) Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

What about `list("Muutujad (sisesta formaadis A,B,C,...): ".replace(' ', ''))`

Downvoter: I meant: this is how you do remove commas from string.

You do not convert your input from string to list and then remove your commas from the list, it's absurd.

you do: `list(input('...').replace(' ', ''))`
or you use split, as pointed out above.

Comment: Yeah, now I understand that removing commas one by one is a dumb idea, but i'm only learing Python so that was the first thing that popped up in my head

Comment: Do not worry, just to let you understand :-)